# How can I unit test a request filter using the ReturnAuthRequired extension method?

Tags: servicestack

In a previous version of serviceStack I was able to write a request filter for authorization this filter used       res.ReturnAuthRequired() when I could not authorize the user.  In the current version of servicestack my unit tests now return a null reference exception because ReturnAuthRequired now calls  httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest(false); which then calls   EndpointHost.CompleteRequest(); How can I unit test this now that there is a reference to the EndpointHost global variable?  Should I not use the extension method?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the callbacks are required to support proper finalization of resources used in the request - e.g. it's required for [Funq's new Request Scope](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) support.

Anyway I've added some null checks [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/24d5a370a98d50cee87b84462edf3c408d94c76c) to make it friendlier when unit testing, which will be available from the next v3.96 release onwards.

Comment: Ok the commit should be in now from v3.97+